# JavaScript Uncaught TypeError: http.createServer is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

When I use `http.createServer` in node.js I get the following error.

```
app.js:145 Uncaught TypeError: http.createServer is not a function
```

The code is as follows:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);

console.log('server started on port 3000');
```

I'm running this code in an `app.js` file using Gulp and my browser's console log to check functionality.

Any ideas on what's causing this error?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to create a server in a browser?

Comment: Nodejs is a backend framework, you should run the app.js through `node app.js` in the terminal.

Comment: @kait it's nodejs code you cannot run it on browser. Please refer this tutorial to execute your code. https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_get_started.asp

Comment: @ShivajiVarma @momocow I'm using Gulp so I thought that would enable me to run node.js that way. Anyway, I tried running `node app.js` as suggested and I still got the error `TypeError: http.createServer is not a function`. Any other ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: where is error coming up? in command line/terminal?  First you need to install nodejs and then you need to go to app.js folder using terminal and execute `node app.js`

Comment: @ShivajiVarma Yes, in command line. I already have nodejs installed and it's up to date, and I have navigated to the folder containing app.js and then run the command `node app.js`. Still getting that error.

Comment: Where is onRequest function defined? Define it with some console.log and check....